# Access of Excel or CSV by Multiple Users at the Same Time

Tags: excel, csv, selenium-webdriver

I m Working on **Performance Testing** using **Selenium Webdriver**(*Selenium Grid* Concept). The Requirement is to run the Testcases in **Parallel** by logging into the application with Usernames provided in **Excel** or **CSV**.

The Question is, Can All the users(*say* 100) can access the **CSV** or **Excel** file at the Same Time to Fetch the Usernames ? Is that Possible ? If No, what can be the Workaround for the Same

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible as long as you are doing only READ operations.

Comment: That will affect parallel execution right? Failure of Testcases more often? Does that affect Test Case Execution Timing? Manually access of Excel 5 times in parallel makes xls to behave improperly. How it is different in Automation with access of 100 users in parallel?